# Merging in to file while handling updates

Tags: java, hashmap, writetofile

I am saving an index of terms in a HashMap, where String is term and List if of documents this term was found in.

```
 private static Map<String, List<Integer>> termMap;
```

This hashmap contains index for the terms found in the document. But the number of terms is considerably large. So i plan to write the map to disk from time to time and flush the map. I have written the code and it is writing the map to disk.

```
 fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("files/termMap.txt");
                           objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
                           objectOutputStream.writeObject(authMap);
                           objectOutputStream.close();
```

But when trying to write to disk the second time and so on, I am unable to check for terms that are already there and update the list of docs rather than replacing them, like I would generally do with hashmap using the below code,

```
if (termMap.containsKey(key)) {

                                   termMap.get(key).add(valueId);

                           } else {
                                   List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                                   list.add(valueId);
                                   termMap.put(key, list);
                           }
```

Kindly help!

Comment: Why does your solution not work?

Comment: Using a database for the disk storage would make this much easier. Otherwise you would need a sophisticated design to allow updating of the list of numbers for a String.  Writing an object doesn't allow for easy updating of what is on file. Or write a merge program to read all the objects and merge the lists